# The rounding mode of floating point numbers in C language When the mantissa of a floating point number exceeds 23 bits how to round the excess part

Tags: c, floating-point

In the calculation

```
123456789 (1 110 1011 0111 1001 1010 0010 101) 
      +20 (                            10 100)
```

the result in C is 123456816 (1 110 1011 0111 1001 1010 0110 000) I find it seems to be rounded up but in the calculation

```
123456785 (1 110 1011 0111 1001 1010 0010 001)
      +20 (                            10 100)
```

(the result is 123456800) At this point it looks like rounding down and the two together look like rounding even

but

```
123456809 (1 110 1011 0111 1001 1010 0101 001)
```

Again, `123456808 (1 110 1011 0111 1001 1010 0101 000)` doesn't make sense

I tried to find the answer on Google and summed up the netizens' opinions were rounded nearby, but it still did not match the above results, so I think there may be some details I do not know,  so I hope you can help me to figure out this problem

---

Adding code to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float x = 123456789.f;
    float y = 20.f;
    
    long m = 123456789L;
    long n = 20L;
    
    printf("As Floats, sum is: %0.1f\n", x+y);
    printf("As Longs,  sum is: %ld\n", m + n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
As Floats, sum is: 123456816.0
As Longs,  sum is: 123456809
```

Comment: A) Show your C code. B) Are you aware of limitations of floating point values?

Comment: The C language does not specify many particulars about floating point behavior.  In practice, nearly all implementations now use IEEE-754 floating-point formats and operations, but IEEE defines several alternative rounding modes from which a C implementation can choose. IEEE defines the default to be round-to-even, but that does not necessarily bind C implementations.

Comment: It didn't take google long to propose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Rounding_modes Doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code does not contain a floating-point addition of 123,456,789 and 20. It contains an addition of 123,456,792 and 20. There are multiple steps (the following uses the format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32, which has 24-bit significands):

- In `float x = 123456789.f;`, the numeral `123456789.` is converted to `float`. The result of the conversion is the nearest representable value, 123,456,792, equivalent to +15,432,099•2<sup>3</sup>. Note that, in this form, the significand, 15,432,099, fits in 24 bits. (The next lower representable value is +15,432,098•2<sup>3</sup> = 123,456,784, and that is further from 123,456,789.)
- In `float y = 20.f;`, the numeral `20.` is converted to `float`. The result of the conversion is the nearest representable value, 20.
- In `x+y`, the two `float` values are added, so we are adding 123,456,792 and 20. The result using real-number arithmetic would be +15,432,099•2<sup>3</sup> + 20 = +15,432,101.5•2<sup>3</sup>. However, 15,432,101.5 requires 25 bits, so it does not fit in the `float` format. The two nearest representable significands are 15,432,101 and 15,432,102. They are equally near, and the rule is to use the one with the even low digit. So the result is +15,432,102•2<sup>3</sup> = 123,456,816.

Comment: Congratulations on 200k!

Comment: @chux to 3 sig. fig.!

Comment: Now Eric's exceeded 200k flatly, no playing with rounding needed.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely，
Is it possible to understand the operation process of two floating point numbers in this way, when the two floating point numbers before the operation, if there are two floating point numbers that can not be accurately represented, the first round before the operation and then the floating point operation, the result of the operation after a check whether it can be accurately represented, if it can be the final answer of the operation, If not, the nearest round is performed again, and the result after rounding is the final answer

Comment: @Nikola_Hotz: It is better to understand the situation not as that numbers are converted to floating-point before an operation but that numbers in source code are converted to floating-point during compilation (or during other parsing of the source code, for scripting languages).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I learned a lot